# psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly (Airflow in AWS, connection drops on both sides)

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, airflow, psycopg2

We have an Airflow instance running in AWS Fargate. It connects to an on-premise Postgres server (on Windows) and tries to load data from a (complicated) view. It uses a `PostgresHook` for that. However, the task in the DAG fails in Airflow with this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py", line 120, in get_records
    cur.execute(sql)
psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

A while ago, the error occurred after some 10-15 minutes. Now, it occurs faster, after 5 minutes or even faster.

I have looked in the Postgres logs, that shows (confusingly) that it was the client that closed the connection:

```
LOG:  could not send data to client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
FATAL:  connection to client lost
```

I have tried a bunch of potential solutions already.

**Without Airflow**
Connnecting to the server outside of Airflow, using `psycopg2` directly: works (using the complicated view).

**Different table**
Trying to load data from a different table from Airflow in the cloud: works, finishes quickly too. So this "timeout" only occurs because the query takes a while.

**Running the Airflow container locally**
At first I could reproduce this issue, but I (think I) solved it by adding some extra parameters in the postgres connection string: `keepalives=1&keepalives_idle=60&keepalives_interval=60`. However, I cannot reproduce this fix in the Airflow in the cloud, because when I add these parameters there, the error remains.

**Increase timeouts**
See above, I added keepalives, but I also tried to reason about other potential timeouts. I added a timeout `execution_timeout` to the DAG arguments, to no avail. We also checked networking timeouts, but given the irregular pattern of the connection failures, it doesn't really sound like such a hard timeout...

I am at a loss here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: we have solved this problem through a workaround. Instead of keeping the connection open while the complex view is being queried, we have turned the connection into an asynchronous connection (i.e., `aconn = psycopg2.connect(database='test', async=1)` from [psycopg docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#asynchronous-support)). Furthermore, we have turned the view into a materialized view, such that we only call a `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` through the asynchronous connection, and then we can just `SELECT *` on the materialized view a while later, which is very fast.